# Open files with mono gtk# on Mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, gtk#

I developped an application for mac using mono and gtk#.
The problem is the default filehandler.
I register my application using this Info.plist (snippet)

```
...
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Filetype</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>file.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ext</string>
            <string>EXT</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
....
```

It registers correctly (the icon is matching, opens my application), but whenever I open the file following message appears:

```
The document "test.ext" could not be opened. mono cannot open files of this type.
```

So how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself:

1. Include https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacInterop to your project.
2. use this code

   ```
   ApplicationEvents.OpenDocuments+= delegate (object sender, ApplicationDocumentEventArgs e) {
       if (e.Documents != null && e.Documents.Count > 0) {
           // e.Documents holds the files
       }
       e.Handled = true;
   };
   ```